# Is there ready solution or I need custom UIView?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview

I'm developing time manager for iOS and need to create something like on picture below. This is list of tasks for week.

[image: Week/Day task list]

- Green box represents which day (monday, sunday, etc...)
- Black box represents single task
- Blue box represents button to add new task

As I understand I need to create custom UIView to implement this design, am I right? Maybe there is ready library which I can to use?

Thank you in advance.
Anatoly.

Comment: You don't want to bring this UI abomination to iOS, do you?

Comment: don't worry, it's only mockup :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add some UIImageview and UIButtons over UIView.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Go for custom. That is best!

Meanwhile have a look here, if you can find something helpful. There are some custom controls with the source code too for cocoa.

```
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not really looked at the collections view stuff in iOS 6 yet, but I would think that might be a good match.  ( I think that it's existence is not NDA, but further details would be).

I don't think there is anything to directly support this kind of layout in iOS 5, maybe you could use 6 UITableViews for the central section.

Comment: I also thought to mix UITableViews but wasn't sure if I'm right, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: There must be some reason the table view tells the table view controller which table is originating each message.